# Sails/Angular Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: angularjs, node.js, model-view-controller, cors, sails.js

I have an angular app as frontend on localhost:9000 and sails as backend on loclahost:1337

In the angular app I do this to query the server:

```
angular.module('webApp')
.controller('FoodCtrl', function($scope, $resource) {

    var Food = $resource('http://localhost:1337/food', {
        id: '@id'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }   
    }); 

    $scope.food = new Food();
    $scope.foodList = Food.query();

    $scope.saveFood = function() {

        var method = $scope.food.id ? '$update' : '$save';

        $scope.food[method]({}, function() {

            $scope.food = new Food();
            $scope.foodList = Food.query();

            console.log("Saved!!");
        })
    };
```

The behaviour is a bit strange. If I go to the angular app and try to trigger the saveFood function from Firefox:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at localhost:1337/food. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

From Chrome is a bit different. Sometimes I get the CORS error and sometimes not, sometimes the model on the server is even updated with the value... But the page shows "Cannot POST/"

Now in my sails app I have enabled CORS just like this:
https://github.com/tarlepp/angular-sailsjs-boilerplate/blob/master/backend/config/cors.js#L71

edit: when I check the header of the request I see 2 post, one on localhost:1337/food which contains Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost:9000 and the other one to localhost:9000/#/food which don't and get 404

This is an exemple output from the chrome console:

```
2Navigated to http://localhost:9000/
(index):1 POST http://localhost:9000/ 404 (Not Found)
2Navigated to http://localhost:9000/
(index):1 POST http://localhost:9000/ 404 (Not Found)
2Navigated to http://localhost:9000/
food.js:33 Saved!!
(index):1 POST http://localhost:9000/ 404 (Not Found)
Navigated to http://localhost:9000/
```

So one time it doesn't post it and the other it does. But I always get "Cannot POST /" on the page
If you want to reproduce it all the code and steps are here:
http://okamuuu.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/04/10/135240

Answer (score 1):

Sails.js provides configuration for CORS under `config/cors`.

You can specify there which foreign hosts are allowed to request your data.

Answer (score 0):

Port has an colon and it gets stripped you need to escape it

try with single '\' or double '\' backslashes

```
http://localhost\:1337/
```

or

```
http://localhost\\:1337/
```

code

```
$resource('http://localhost\:1337/food', {
        id: '@id'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }   
    });
```

Comment: Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://localhost:1337:1337/food

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this as your first route in config/routes.js

```
'OPTIONS /*': function(req, res) {return res.send(200);},
```

Angular runs a preflight OPTIONS request to check what is authorized. You need to respond to this request.

Comment: check your console and see if your seeing the OPTIONS request getting called and responded too.

Comment: Depends... Sometimes the option is accepted sometimes it's 404

Comment: Hmmmm, that does sound odd. A 404 error on the OPTIONS request is what you would expect without that line of code. For you to get it intermittently I think suggests a larger problem. I would first try with Postman to eliminate or single out the client as the issue?

Comment: Note that the 404 is not always on option, most of the time it's on the post. DIdn't know about Postman I'm going to check it out thx

Comment: If postman does the same as your client browsers, then I would suggest posting your Routes and Policies (and any other custom middleware).